# how to group consecutive days based on another category in R

Tags: r, group-by

I would like to use the following data frame

```
time <- c("01/01/1951", "02/01/1951", "03/01/1951", "04/01/1951", "03/03/1953", "04/03/1953", "05/03/1953", "06/03/1953", "02/01/1951", "03/01/1951", "04/01/1951", "05/01/1951", "13/03/1953", "14/03/1953", "15/03/1953", "16/03/1953", "01/05/1951", "02/05/1951", "03/05/1951", "04/05/1951", "04/03/1953", "05/03/1953", "06/03/1953", "07/03/1953")
member <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
trainall <- data.frame(time, member)
trainall$time = as.Date(trainall$time,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

to order it by group of consecutive days based on the members. therefore if the same days are in member 2 and 1 I dont want them grouped together as consecutive! 
ultimately I want a new column making this group

this is what I tried but it didnt work

```
y = sort(trainall$time)
trainall$g = cumsum(c(1, abs(y[-length(y)] - y[-1]) > 1))
```

this is the outcome I want.

```
 trainall
     time       member g
1  01/01/1951      1 1
2  02/01/1951      1 1
3  03/01/1951      1 1
4  04/01/1951      1 1
5  03/03/1953      1 2
6  04/03/1953      1 2
7  05/03/1953      1 2
8  06/03/1953      1 2
9  02/01/1951      2 3
10 03/01/1951      2 3
11 04/01/1951      2 3
12 05/01/1951      2 3
13 13/03/1953      2 4
14 14/03/1953      2 4
15 15/03/1953      2 4
16 16/03/1953      2 4
17 01/05/1951      3 5
18 02/05/1951      3 5
19 03/05/1951      3 5
20 04/05/1951      3 5
21 04/03/1953      3 6
22 05/03/1953      3 6
23 06/03/1953      3 6
24 07/03/1953      3 6
```

ultimately this is the outcome I want. however, here I did it manually and my actual data frame is much much larger (16 members)

anyone know how to easily do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of logical values as integers 0 and 1 and your friend `diff` can do the trick. Something like this should do it, provided that your data is sorted by member and time.

```
# Your data
time <- c("01/01/1951", "02/01/1951", "03/01/1951", "04/01/1951", "03/03/1953", "04/03/1953", "05/03/1953", "06/03/1953", "02/01/1951", "03/01/1951", "04/01/1951", "05/01/1951", "13/03/1953", "14/03/1953", "15/03/1953", "16/03/1953", "01/05/1951", "02/05/1951", "03/05/1951", "04/05/1951", "04/03/1953", "05/03/1953", "06/03/1953", "07/03/1953")
member <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
trainall <- data.frame(time, member)
trainall$time = as.Date(trainall$time,format="%d/%m/%Y")

# Creating column g
trainall$g <- cumsum(c(1, (abs(diff(trainall$time)) + diff(trainall$member))!=1))
print(trainall)
#         time member g
#1  1951-01-01      1 1
#2  1951-01-02      1 1
#3  1951-01-03      1 1
#4  1951-01-04      1 1
#5  1953-03-03      1 2
#6  1953-03-04      1 2
#7  1953-03-05      1 2
#8  1953-03-06      1 2
#9  1951-01-02      2 3
#10 1951-01-03      2 3
#11 1951-01-04      2 3
#12 1951-01-05      2 3
#13 1953-03-13      2 4
#14 1953-03-14      2 4
#15 1953-03-15      2 4
#16 1953-03-16      2 4
#17 1951-05-01      3 5
#18 1951-05-02      3 5
#19 1951-05-03      3 5
#20 1951-05-04      3 5
#21 1953-03-04      3 6
#22 1953-03-05      3 6
#23 1953-03-06      3 6
#24 1953-03-07      3 6
```

Edit: Added `abs()` around the time difference. I guess the `abs` cannot strictly be omitted as you could have a time difference of -2 days when the member changes, which cause the sum to be 1.

Edit 2: Re. your extra comment, try

```
trainall$G <- sequence(table(trainall$g))
```

Comment: awesome! thank you, now I would like to number the rows within the groups in a new column. hence, the first date in g =1 is 1, the second date in G=1 2 etc. and then the first date in g = 2 is 1 again etc. any ideas?

Comment: @Judith I've updated my answer. That's my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `.GRP` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(trainall)[, g := .GRP, .(member, grp = cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(time) != 1)))]
trainall
#          time member g
# 1: 1951-01-01      1 1
# 2: 1951-01-02      1 1
# 3: 1951-01-03      1 1
# 4: 1951-01-04      1 1
# 5: 1953-03-03      1 2
# 6: 1953-03-04      1 2
# 7: 1953-03-05      1 2
# 8: 1953-03-06      1 2
# 9: 1951-01-02      2 3
#10: 1951-01-03      2 3
#11: 1951-01-04      2 3
#12: 1951-01-05      2 3
#13: 1953-03-13      2 4
#14: 1953-03-14      2 4
#15: 1953-03-15      2 4
#16: 1953-03-16      2 4
#17: 1951-05-01      3 5
#18: 1951-05-02      3 5
#19: 1951-05-03      3 5
#20: 1951-05-04      3 5
#21: 1953-03-04      3 6
#22: 1953-03-05      3 6
#23: 1953-03-06      3 6
#24: 1953-03-07      3 6
```